# Infowindow Mouse Wheel in Mozilla Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, google-maps-api-3

I have a infowindow in Google Maps and I want it to scroll when the mouse is over it.

Just to clarify, I want to keep the map scroll ( `scrollwheel: true`).

In Google Chrome it works fine. However, when I open it using Mozilla Firefox, instead of scrolling the DIV, it scrolls the map.

How could I force the DIV to scroll in Firefox too?

[Fiddle Example here](http://jsfiddle.net/wLuhktu4/25/) (Open it in chrome and firefox to see the difference)

```
.iw-content {
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

google.maps.event.addListener(MyMarker, 'click', function(event) {
var content = '<div class="iw-content">' + 
    '<p><b>Information: </b>X<br></p>  '+
    '<p><b>Information: </b>Y<br></p>  '+
    '<p><b>Information: </b>Z<br></p>  '+

    '</div>';
```